# Why is the attached WMS service not working with QGIS and QGIS2WEB?

Tags: qgis, openlayers, qgis2web

I am using QGIS2WEB (open layers) to develop a small platform with geodata. I am having trouble integrating the following WMS service into my webmap:

http://geoportal.frankfurt.de/opendata/bodenrichtwerte-2018.exe?service=WMS&request=GetCapabilities&

Using QGIS2WEB, no output is displayed, neither in the preview nor in the export. Other WMS services work. What could be the problem?

I work with QGIS (2.18.22) and QGIS2WEB (2.34.0).

---

From @TomChadwin'S comment, after activating "Match project CRS", the export of all WMS layers was almost correctly executed with OpenLayers. Unfortunately, Leaflet does not work.

However, a part of the OSM basemap is now not displayed in the northern part of the webmap. White background only.

Any ideas why the basemap doesn't fill the whole screen?

[image]

These are my settings:
[image]

Comment: Please specify where exactly nothing is shown. In QGIS or in the resulting web map in your browser? If the latter, check your error console for relevant output. It loads fine for me in QGIS.

Comment: Works for me in QGIS desktop by using shorter `http://geoportal.frankfurt.de/opendata/bodenrichtwerte-2018.exe?` as a connection string.

Comment: It loads fine for me in QGIS, too. But it's not being exported into my webmap nor displayed in the preview, using QGIS2WEB .

Comment: The service doesn't support typical web map projections (it only supports EPSG:25832 and EPSG:31467) are you making GetMap requests in those projections in your web map?

Comment: Check "Match project CRS", and export in Leaflet format - that works for me. I don't know why it's not displaying in OpenLayers.

Comment: @tomchadwin that sounds like an answer to me

Comment: @Ian Turton I didn't give it as an answer because the OP's map was OpenLayers. This suggestion therefore felt like a workaround, not a solution.

Comment: For me, it works with Openlayers using EPSG:25832 as project CRS, but not with leaflet (which seems to fall back to EPSG:4326).

Comment: Almost done. Any ideas why the basemap doesn't fill the whole screen (see picture above)?

Comment: Did you restrict to extent? Then you don't get more than that.